# passing the selected parameter value from ssrs report to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I need to get the selected value of a parameter and use it in my code. Is there any events where I can capture the parameter values. Please let me know

Comment: Please provide more detail:  how does the user select the parameter?  Are you displaying the report in the report viewer control or rendering it programmatically?  Are you talking about the Code section of the report or about an ASP.NET page that contains the report viewer?  Etc.

Comment: I am displaying a report through report viewer control. the report is displayed with the selected parameters selected by the user. now their is a parameter by name city. I would like to get the selected city by the user  and use it in my asp.net page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the answer is yes.

There's an event on the ReportViewer web control called [SubmittingParameterValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.submittingparametervalues%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you can handle in the host page.  This has a [ReportParametersEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameterseventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) parameter, which in turn has a [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameterseventargs.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.

The `Parameters` property is a collection of `ReportParameter` objects.  The `ReportParameter` class has `Name` and `Values` properties.

You can use the `Name` property to find the parameter you're interested in.  The `Values` property, which is a collection of strings, should contain the value submitted.